# Can't get chai.spy.on to work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

Please don't suggest to use Sinon. I want to get chai-spies specifically chai.spy.on working with your help. Basically, I have this spec. Inside my initialize method in PatientController, I call this.initializePatientEvents();

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.patientController = new PatientController({model: new Backbone.Model(PatientModel)});
});

it('executes this.initializePatientEvents', function () {
  let spy = chai.spy.on(this.patientController, 'initializePatientEvents');
  expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
});
```

However, the test is failing with this error

```
AssertionError: expected { Spy } to have been called
at Context.<anonymous>
```

I spent almost 3 hours now with no luck! :(

Comment: Not sure if this is related but what does `this` refer to within the anonymous function inside the beforeEach? Typically when I do unit testing, I'll define the variables outside of the beforeEach and then assign them their values within the beforeEach. Try declaring a variable `patientController` outside of the beforeEach and then assigning the `new PatientController` object within the beforeEach.

Comment: are you saying to use patientController rather than this.patientController?

Comment: 1) `beforeEach`, `describe`, and `it` are features of your test framework (mocha / jasmine / sinon), so your question doesn't really make any sense. 2) Even if the `beforeEach` is running, thats prior to you registering the spy so your initializePatientEvents probably ran from its constructor (prior to spy registration). You need a way to call initializePatientEvents because you are doing nothing to trigger it in your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving my comment above to a response here:

Looking at your code, I'm just not sure what the `this` reference refers to. And based on your error message, it seems like its related to something about the context. Therefore, I'd try something like this:

```
var patientController;

beforeEach(function() {
    patientController = new PatientController({model: new Backbone.Model(PatientModel)});
});

it('executes this.initializePatientEvents', function () {
    let spy = chai.spy.on(patientController, 'initializePatientEvents');
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
});
```

If this doesn't work, then its more specific to your implementation of `patientController` and the `initializePatientEvents` method, and not something related to chai.spy.

**EDIT:**
Here's something I set up locally and I was able to get a passing test. The main difference is that instead of using Backbone, I just created my own constructor function.

```
"use strict";
var chai = require("chai");
var sinon = require("sinon");
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.use(sinonChai);
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should();

describe("PatientController Test", function() {
    var PatientController;
    var initializePatientEventsSpy;
    var patient;

    beforeEach(function() {
        PatientController = function(name, age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.initializePatientEvents();
        };

        PatientController.prototype.initializePatientEvents = function() {
            console.log("Do some initialization stuff here");
        };

        initializePatientEventsSpy = sinon.spy(PatientController.prototype, "initializePatientEvents");
    });

    it("should test initializePatientEvents was called", function() {
        patient = new PatientController("Willson", 30);
        initializePatientEventsSpy.should.have.been.called;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I tried and still didn't work. I may need to troubleshoot my controller. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding the process incorrectly. Am I right that the 2nd param should point to a regular function defined in the context, in this case, it's patientController? I hope someone can provide a working jsfiddle or even a quick code in github which has chai-spies.

Comment: Taking a look now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the `PatientController` constructor is what calls `initializePatientEvents`, then the timing of your spy creation is a bit off. Currently, the order of your spy-function relationship is:

1. Call function
2. Spy on function
3. Expect spied on function to have ben called

Because the function is not being spied on when it is called, the spy misses the call entirely. What the order should be is:

1. Spy on function
2. Call function
3. Expect spied on function to have ben called

However, you are in the sticky situation where the object you are spying on doesn't exist until after the constructor is called. One workaround would be to assert that the effects of the `initializePatientEvents` have taken place instead of asserting that the function was called.